# WebGL in XML documents

Tags: javascript, html, xml, webgl

I want to process my XML documents directly from itself and render some of its data/elements using WebGL. Therefore, I use xhtml:script to run my JavaScript code.

WebGL API is available (for example window.WebGLRenderingContext).
But when I try to get the WebGl context from the canvas element (see the code below), I get null.

- Why is the WebGL context not available?
- How can I achieve the expected behaviour?

The same JavaScript code works fine in a simple HTML document.
I use Chrome browser.

XML document (simplified for testing):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<myWorld>
<sphere></sphere>
<cube></cube>
<xhtml:script xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
            src="process.js"
            type="application/javascript"/>
</myWorld>
```

JavaScript code (process.js):

```
//preparing for WebGL stuff
var impl = document.implementation,
htmlDoc = impl.createHTMLDocument("Hello");

// use newly created HTML document to create complete canvas object, 
// because our XML document does not know about canvas and therefore
// it creates simple Element node with 'canvas' tag name
var canvas = htmlDoc.createElement('canvas');

//everything okay
console.log(canvas);

//logs null. Why?
console.log(canvas.getContext('experimental-webgl'));
```

Comment: Is the document in the window loaded state? Maybe WebGL is not available until the whole document is loaded.

Comment: Or maybe security limits WebGL for normal HTML documents only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say you're using Chrome; I believe this is a bug in Chrome (and apparently IE) — I certainly can't justify the behaviour from the spec. (Here's a [bug](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=352282) for Chrome, and [one](https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/833542/webgl-context-creation-error-not-fired-from-canvas-owned-by-script-created-document) for IE.)

In short: given a document from `document.implementation.createHTMLDocument` (or `document.implementation.createDocument`), Chrome cannot create a WebGL context.

However, there's no need to do this. You can create a canvas element in the current document:

```
 // create an HTML canvas element
var canvas = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml", "canvas");
console.log(canvas);
 // you probably ought use "webgl" and not "experimental-webgl" nowadays!
console.log(canvas.getContext('webgl'));
```